# about 30% iap-purchase event missed

Tags: in-app-purchase

the version of firebase analytics sdk of our app is 21.3.0, and the purchase event should be tracked automatically, but we found some purchase event missed, compare with the order number from Google play, it seems only 70 percent purchase event found on firebase.

since the purchase event tracking is automatically, it seems there is nothing to be done expect upgrade the SDK, and we have upgraded the SDK to 21.3.0, but the problem is still exist.